# Why are some fonts listed with ls shown in red and with a star at the end of the filename?

Tags: macos, terminal, font

I am trying to use some fonts in ImageMagick which are not showing up, despite me using the same script that works on another Mac. Listing the fonts in /Library/Fonts I can see that the missing fonts are listed differently when I use the `ls -lahFG` command.

What does this way of listing files mean?

[image: Some fonts are listed differently in Terminal]

Answer (score 2):

It means the font files are marked as executable, i.e. they contain code which can be executed. This is clearly incorrect for what should be a font file with no concept of being executed.

Comment: Generally speaking, while most files marked as executable actually are, nonetheless, just because any given file is marked as executable, it doesn't necessarily mean it actually contains code that can be executed. In this particular case the **Roboto-*.ttf**  files are erroneously set as executable at the time they were extracted from the roboto-master.zip file from [https://github.com/google/roboto](https://github.com/google/roboto).

Comment: a `chmod a-x Roboto*.ttf` (maybe with `sudo`) will remove the unnecessary executable flag.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers =) I will re-chmod them and see if they still don't show up in ImageMagick. =)